# The cookie doesn't store the right value

Tags: c#, asp.net, http, cookies

in asp.net c# I created a cookie:

```
HttpCookie passCookie = new HttpCookie("passC");
passCookie.Value = Session["pass"].ToString();
passCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1);
Response.Cookies.Add(passCookie);
```

But when the password was ended with & in stored it without it.
For example, instead of Sl98&& it stored Sl98& and instead of Sl9&8& it stored Sl9&8.

Why does it behave this way and how can I fix it?

Thank you

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. I have closed your question as a duplicate. You can find your answer in that question.